# Can antimicrobial peptides be called antibiotics?

Tags: immunology

Antibiotic peptides are present in almost all multicellular eukaryotes. So can they be called antibiotics ? ( which are usually defined only for fungi and bacteria )

Answer (score 1):

[Antibiotic peptides are definitely antibiotics](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1383011).  They are often referred to more specifically as peptides because the fact implies that they are less toxic and conveys some important understanding of how they work.  Not sure if they all form pores in the target cell, but that's how magainins work.